# How to define emacs keybinding 'C-c C-c'?

Tags: emacs

I want to bind the 'C-c C-c' to a custom command, don't know how to.

I tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") 'suspend-emacs)`, but it seams not work.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check to see what it's set to now?  C-h k C-c C-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very likely that the local binding of <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> in the current buffer is shadowing the global binding that you make with `global-set-key`. Conventionally, key sequences consisting of <kbd>C-c</kbd> followed by a control character are reserved for major modes. For instance, CC Mode gives <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> a local binding as `comment-region`. Key sequences consisting of <kbd>C-c</kbd> and a letter (either upper or lower case) are set aside for users:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") 'suspend-emacs)
```

And you may not want to bind `suspend-emacs` to a new key sequece. `suspend-frame`, which is bound to <kbd>C-z</kbd> and <kbd>C-x C-z</kbd> by default, calls `suspend-emacs` for us when it is invoked from the (controlling) tty device.